# Question about terminology for functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a specific term that refers to the set of points in the codomain of a function to which the function does not assign values?

Comment: Umm... "not in the co-domain" perhaps?

Comment: "not in the image/range". Or "complement of the range/image"

Answer (score 1):

Fix a relation $R\subseteq X\times Y$. $X$ is usually called *domain* or *set of departure*; $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ is usually called *domain of definition* or *active domain* (see [Frank 1970](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)) or *preimage* or *inverse image*; $\operatorname{ran}(R)$ is usually called *range* or *active codomain* (see [Frank 1970](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)) or *image*; $\operatorname{field}(R)=\operatorname{dom}(R)\cup \operatorname{ran}(R)$ is usually called *field*; $Y$ is usually called *codomain* or *set of destination*.

While there are no popular names for the sets $X-\operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $Y-\operatorname{ran}(R)$. For convenience, you could name them by yourself as long as the names are accurate. For example, since $\operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $\operatorname{ran}(R)$ are called active domain and active codomain respectively, we can call $X-\operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $Y-\operatorname{ran}(R)$ as *inactive domain* and *inactive codomain* repectively, and set $\operatorname{iad}(R)=X-\operatorname{dom}(R)$ and $\operatorname{iacd}(R)=Y-\operatorname{ran}(R)$.

Now we can summarize them as a table:

$$
\begin{array}{lllll}
\textbf{Set / Name / Class}&1&2&3&4\\
X&\text{domain}&-&-&\text{set of departure}\\
\operatorname{dom}(R)&\text{domain of definition}&\text{active domain}&\text{inverse image / preimage}&-\\
\operatorname{ran}(R)&\text{range}&\text{active codomain}&\text{image}&-\\
Y&\text{codomain}&-&-&\text{set of destination}\\
\operatorname{field}(R)&\text{field}&-&-&-\\
\operatorname{iad}(R)&-&\text{inactive domain}&-&-\\
\operatorname{iacd}(R)&-&\text{inactive codomain}&-&-\\
\end{array}
$$

Since a function $f:X\to Y$ is also a relation, then the names for sets related to functions should be the same as relations. And note that since $X=\operatorname{dom}(f)$, they share the names with each other.